# Search the field with different letters in between the line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Sample of text:

```
ERROR IN CONNECTING TO NODE:**NT**SX01,CMS
ERROR IN CONNECTING TO NODE:**USSP**SX01,CMS
ERROR IN CONNECTING TO NODE:**PT**SX01,CMS
```

Want to grep the three lines in the same command.

```
grep "ERROR IN CONNECTING TO NODE:?SX01,CMS"
```

What should I put in place of question mark so that all the three lines will grep?

Comment: Are there literal `*` characters in your input, or is that an attempt to highlight the text that you wish to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match any characters `.*` betweeen `NODE:` and `SX01,CMS`, you can use

```
grep "^ERROR IN CONNECTING TO NODE:.*SX01,CMS$" file
```

The `^` matches the beginning of the line and `$` matches the end of the line.

If you want to include the literal `**` before and after `NT`, `USSP` and `PT`:

```
grep "^ERROR IN CONNECTING TO NODE:\*\*.*\*\*SX01,CMS$" file
```

If you want to include any letters between `**` and `**`:

```
grep "^ERROR IN CONNECTING TO NODE:\*\*[A-Z]*\*\*SX01,CMS$" file
```

And to make it even more specific: `grep` for the strings `NT` or `USSP` or `PT`:

```
grep "^ERROR IN CONNECTING TO NODE:\*\*\(NT\|USSP\|PT\)\*\*SX01,CMS$" file
```